# Weak decay iff or if strangeness changes?

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction

I know that for a decay if the strangeness changes then the decay is a weak decay because strangeness is conserved in both strong decays and electromagnetic decays. However, is it also true that if a weak decay occurs the strangeness must also change? i.e. do we have:
$$\text{weak decay} \iff \Delta S\ne0$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$\text{weak decay} \Leftarrow \Delta S\ne0$$
If it is the latter, is their another necessary and sufficient condition (apart from looking at timescales) to see if a decay is weak?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding type of force interaction in particle decays](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263799/)

Answer (score 1):

No, a weak decay doesn't imply a change of $S$. For example, the decay of the neutron – the basic part of the beta-decay – has $S=0$ both in the initial and final state. So the first proposition is false and only the second one is true.